# How to keep the order of stacks in ggplot using stat='identity'?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While plotting a stacked bar plot using `stack='identity'` I noticed that the order of the stacks is different in each bar, in a seemingly random manner. This is the plot using `stat='bin'`, that is, ggplot calculates the number of elements in each category on the fly before plotting (`data.table` is there for later):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

diamonds <- data.table(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

[image]

In each bar, the order of 'cut' follows that of the order of the factors. However, if I summarise before plotting, and use `stat=identity`, this order is lost:

```
diamonds_sum <- diamonds[, list(.N), by=list(cut, clarity)]
ggplot(diamonds_sum, aes(clarity, y=N, fill = cut)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill")
```

[image]

This happens despite the order of the levels in both tables is the same:

```
levels(diamonds_sum$cut) == levels(diamonds$cut)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So the question is 2-fold: (i) why isn't the order of the stacks the same? and (ii) how can this be fixed?

The easy solution is of course use `stat='bin'` all the time, however my real data set has a few milion entries, and summarizing and then plotting is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the order gets mixed-up in your new *data.table* after summarising and `ggplot2` takes the order of the rows as input. Compare for example the output from the following two approaches (just showing the first 10 rows as they illustrate the differences good enough):

```
> diamonds[, .N, by=.(cut, clarity)]
          cut clarity    N
 1:     Ideal     SI2 2598
 2:   Premium     SI1 3575
 3:      Good     VS1  648
 4:   Premium     VS2 3357
 5:      Good     SI2 1081
 6: Very Good    VVS2 1235
 7: Very Good    VVS1  789
 8: Very Good     SI1 3240
 9:      Fair     VS2  261
10: Very Good     VS1 1775

> diamonds[, .N, by=.(cut, clarity)][order(clarity,cut)]
          cut clarity    N
 1:      Fair      I1  210
 2:      Good      I1   96
 3: Very Good      I1   84
 4:   Premium      I1  205
 5:     Ideal      I1  146
 6:      Fair     SI2  466
 7:      Good     SI2 1081
 8: Very Good     SI2 2100
 9:   Premium     SI2 2949
10:     Ideal     SI2 2598
```

As you can see, your original code results in mixed-up rows, while the second approach results in order rows. So, when you do:

```
diamonds_sum <- diamonds[, .N, by=.(cut, clarity)][order(clarity,cut)]
```

and then plot with:

```
ggplot(diamonds_sum, aes(clarity, y=N, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill")
```

you get the desired result:

[image]

---

Also `dplyr` will give you the same behavior. You will then need `arrange` to get the right order. Compare the output of the following two:

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut, clarity) %>% tally()
diamonds %>% group_by(cut, clarity) %>% tally() %>% arrange(clarity,cut)
```

---

Summarising with base R does not result in the problem you are describing. When you do:

```
diamonds_sum <- aggregate(diamonds[,"cut",with=FALSE], list(diamonds$cut,diamonds$clarity), length)
```

and then plot with:

```
ggplot(diamonds_sum, aes(Group.2, y=cut, fill = Group.1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill")
```

you get the correct result:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was under the (false) impression that ggplot did not care about the order of elements in rows, only cared about the order of the factors for the plotted elements. Live and learn.

Comment: @fridaymeetssunday Well, I had that impression as well actually. Your example made me realise that it does matter.